# NodeJS packages -- npm vs. OS' package-manager

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, packaging

We try to install NodeJS packages using the Operating System's package-management (such as `apt`/`dpkg` on Ubuntu), whenever possible.

Yet, for some of them such a package either does not exist or is too outdated -- and for those we use `npm`.

The mixture causes difficulties, when we wish to upgrade because npm would upgrade them all (including the stuff bundled with node itsel), yet we only want it to touch the things, which it installed in the first place...

Is it possible to reliably discern, whether a package *known* to npm (listed in `npm -g ls`) was *installed* by it?

Comment: What about the reverse? Try asking `apt` or `yum` or `dnf` if they installed it.

Comment: @tadman, I would do that -- had there been a clear mapping between npm package names and those of apt. Some times they are the same, other times they are different...

Comment: It's probably better to go all NPM or all Apt, not mix the two.

Comment: Well, `nodejs` itself is installed through apt -- chicken and egg. And nodejs installs a lot of packages listed by npm.

Comment: I haven't found this to be a big deal, but if it's causing a lot of strife, maybe do a source install so Apt doesn't mess around with your stuff.